# IF ELSE insert or replace in a query based on whether the table has a row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to accomplish something like this? How could I be able to do something like this in a query?

The caveat is that I want to change the old pk so for example if it was 888 I want to change it to 999 and still only have 1 row in the table.

```
SET @toReplaceInto := (SELECT `pk` FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `pk` DESC LIMIT 1);
IF @toReplaceInto = NULL THEN
INSERT INTO `my_table` 
  (`pk`,`number`) VALUES (999,2);
ELSE
REPLACE INTO `my_table` 
  (`pk`,`number`) VALUES (999,2,2,3,4,5,6,7) WHERE `pk` = @toReplaceInto;
END IF;
``
```

Comment: Use `INSERT` with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my updates to this question? @Barmar

Comment: You can't do this in a single query. You'll have to write a procedure.

Comment: What if there's already `pk = 999` but it's not the highest key?

Comment: I don't care in this case, I would prefer to do nothing